# Google Cloud Endpoints hard coded client id in Java and the use of useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a question regarding the hard coded nature of client ids in **Google Cloud Endpoint** API using Java.

We have multiple projects with client ids tied to specific projects and have found we have to create project specific **GAE** artefacts (WARs).  This is a less than ideal situation as we use a micro services architecture and there will be a combinatorial explosion of artefacts.

In an attempt to create an environment agnostic artefact we have used a poorly documented feature of the API, the **useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig** attribute.

To illustrate, instead of the following:

```
@Api(
  name = "example", 
  version = "v1",
  scopes = { "example-scope" },
  clientIds = { "example-client-id" },
)
```

We use:

```
@Api( name = "example",
      version = "v1",
      useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE
)
```

However we have heard this feature will be deprecated in an upcoming release.  My question would be, is there something wrong in the way we are building our artefacts?  Also if there is nothing wrong with our build process, do Google recognise this as an issue and do they have any plan to enable the creation of project agnostic GAE artefacts in Java?

Comment: Don't use `useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig`. If you are using OAuth2 rather than ID tokens, you can use Constant.SKIP_CLIENT_ID_CHECK and verify the client ID yourself.

Comment: @saiyr This could be useful but this appears to be only in the Python API, is there a Java equivalent for SKIP_CLIENT_ID_CHECK?

Comment: Yes, look in spi.Constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some guidance from @saiyr we came  up with a solution for this issue and thought it would be helpful to share the answer.

We have bypassed client id assertions in the framework by doing the following:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.Constant;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.GoogleOAuth2Authenticator;

@Api(
  name = "example",
  version = "v1",
  scopes = { Constant.API_EMAIL_SCOPE },
  clientIds = { Constant.SKIP_CLIENT_ID_CHECK },
  authenticators = { ClientIdAuthenticator.class,GoogleOAuth2Authenticator.class }
)
```

Then we created a custom authenticator which took care of the programmatic assertion of the client id:

```
public class ClientIdAuthenticator implements Authenticator { 
  @Override
  public User authenticate(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    // Lookup config from cloud datastore for requestURI
    OAuthService service = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
    String clientId = service.getClientId(Constant.API_EMAIL_SCOPE);
    // Assert clientId contained in datastore configuration
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no better way of handling this situation. Google docs clearly mentions the limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth):

> Note: Because the authorized clientIds must be specified at build
>   time, you must rebuild and redeploy your API backend after adding or
>   changing any client IDs in clientIds or audiences. (You must also
>   update the regenerated jar file for your Android project for an
>   Android client and regenerate the Objective-C library for iOS
>   clients.)

You cannot have a single artifact with externalized clientIds. But, you could automate the process of updating the clientIds using maven [replacer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Apologies, if it wasn't clear in my original posting but we have managed to create a single artefact with external config via the useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig attribute.  Prior to that we had implemented various Maven approaches to this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Since `useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig` is going to be deprecated. The only way is to use maven. :(